# javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException after upgrading to icefaces 1.7.2

Tags: java, seam, icefaces, backwards-compatibility

Hello I've just upgraded icefaces 1.7.1 to 1.7.2 and started to get javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException exceptions after clicking twice on the same link.
I'm using JBoss Seam 2.0.2 and I suppose that it is some stupid mistake I've made during upgrade but I can't figure out what. I've just replaced three jars with newer ones (icefaces.jar, icefaces-comps.jar and icefaces-facelets.jar. Is there anything more I should do? When I switch back to 1.7.1 everything works fine as before.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that ICEfaces is not completely backwards binary compatible and cannot be updated without recompilation of JBoss Seam components. Compatible combinations you may find in the changelog.txt file from JBoss Seam [packages](http://seamframework.org/Seam2/Seam2DistributionDownloads). I've got the following combinations:

- JBoss Seam 2.1.2 and ICEfaces 1.8.0
- JBoss Seam 2.1.1 and ICEfaces 1.7.2 SP1
- JBoss Seam 2.1.0 and ICEfaces 1.7.2
- JBoss Seam 2.0.2 and ICEfaces 1.7.0
- JBoss Seam 2.0.0 and ICEfaces 1.6.1 ([more info](http://support.icesoft.com/jive/entry.jspa?entryID=721&categoryID=71))
- JBoss Seam 1.2.1 and ICEfaces 1.6.0
- JBoss Seam 1.1.0 and ICEfaces 1.5.1

You may read a detailed [1.7.2 changelog](http://www.icefaces.org/releasenotes/icefaces-1.7.2-RN.html#Changes_172) or try to update ICEface or JBoss Seam to the newer version. Also this problem is well discovered at the [icefaces forum](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/10432.page).